# How to make a window transparent, draggable and add some layered components?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jwindow

I don't know how to add a `JLabel` on top of a `JPanel`. I want to display some information in a label on the mobile image. The image is in the `JPanel`. I already managed to make the `JFrame` undecorated.

Output http://i44.tinypic.com/2mhacsj.png

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Window;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

class Remote extends JFrame {
    JPanel p2;

    private Window Remote;

    public Remote() {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        // Set title and default close operation
        setTitle("Transparent Panel");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);
        p2 = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C://Mobile.png"));
        p2.add(label);
        p2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 800));
        add(p2);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(315, 610);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocation(800, 100);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Run in the EDT
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Remote remote = new Remote();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I have 3 Questions:

1. How do I remove the borders [background] surrounding the mobile?
2. How do I add some label in the `JPanel`?
3. How to make the window movable?

Comment: A [transparent version](http://i4.minus.com/iCqJnRyJYliWQ.png) of the mobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should meet your requirements:

```
public void createAndShowGUI() {
    setTitle("Transparent Panel");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setUndecorated(true);
    AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(this, false);

    JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    layeredPane.setBounds(0, 0, 315, 610);

    JLabel mobileImageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C://Mobile.png"));
    mobileImageLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 315, 610);
    layeredPane.add(mobileImageLabel, Integer.valueOf(0));

    JLabel textLabel = new JLabel(" Booting... ");
    textLabel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
    textLabel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    textLabel.setBounds(26, 59, 263, 495);
    layeredPane.add(textLabel, Integer.valueOf(1));

    setContentPane(layeredPane);

    setSize(315, 610);
    setLocation(800, 100);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

**For a draggable window, call this method from your `Remote()` constructor**:

```
public void addListeners() {
    final Point offset = new Point();
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {
            offset.setLocation(e.getPoint());
        }
    });
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(final MouseEvent e) {
            setLocation(e.getXOnScreen()-offset.x, e.getYOnScreen()-offset.y);
        }
    });
}
```

**Further notes**:

- instead of `JFrame.add()` use: `getContentPane().add()` or `setContentPane()`
- `AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque()` removes the gray background of an undecorated frame
- a `JLayeredPane` can be used to stack components on top of each other
- the layout in the `JLayeredPane` has to be done manually

---

**It should now look something like this:**:

[image: result: a transparent jframe with an image and label on top]

Comment: New requirements, eh?

Comment: Suggestion: You can append that to your question + what you have tried so far to solve this additional problem. I'll look into this later.

Comment: @ArulNadhan: So, you've givin' it a try?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly. So you need to remove the title bar and display the frame as a mobile?

In that case you have to do the following code to remove the title bar

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Already there
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame.setUndecorated(true);
```

and than you can do this to set the background image:

```
setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("path/to/image.jpg")));
```